# AppsFlyer Onelink Deeplinking Debugging

Tags: ios, deep-linking, deeplink, appsflyer, appsflyer-ios-sdk

I'm using AppsFlyer to test retargeting feature. I've implemented deep-linking using Firebase.

I launch the app on my device using Xcode and click the link below which launches the browser and redirects to AppStore. Since I'm running the debug build directly on the device, it detects as "App not installed".

How can I make sure the link directly opens my App and not redirect to the App store ?

The link is of format:

https://Mycompany.onelink.me/12345678?pid=twitter&c=Paywall&af_dp=MyApp%3A%2F%2FUpgrade&af_web_dp=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.MyCompany.com%2Ffeatures-and-benefits%2Fmobile&is_retargeting=true

Answer (score 1):

In general, you need to configure `Universal Links` / `URL Schemes` in your xCode project. Most developers choose Universal Links as they are more secure and work better for most use-cases.

You will also need access the `Configure OneLink` page on the AppsFlyer dashboard, in order to create a unique OneLink ID for your application, set up the subdomain for your OneLink and input some additional data that is used for authentication (as Universal Links are secure).

You can find all the detailed info and instructions here: https://support.appsflyer.com/hc/en-us/articles/208874366

As this requires a setup on both the client side and and server side, you can request some assistance with the server side configurations and additional instructions on client side configurations at support@appsflyer.com

Comment: Can you help with this issue: https://github.com/AppsFlyerSDK/appsflyer-capacitor-plugin/issues/41